# Nginx regex to match single path

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

Suppose I have these paths:

```
/
/something # this path is variable (any characters except /)
/api/v1/something
```

What is the best nginx config to capture this requirement? The following is not working for m:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location ~^/(?:.*)$ {
        ...
    }
    location / {
        ...
    }
    location /api/v1/something {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the "somthing" in `/api/v1/...` also a variable length string?

Comment: Nope, that is a route!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression matches everything which means it always wins! See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to understand how Nginx chooses which `location` block to process a request.

You do not need to use a regular expression `location`.

First define `location` blocks for the single URIs using the `=` operator:

```
location = / { ... }
location = /api/v1/foo { ... }
```

Then use the default `location` to catch anything else:

```
location / { ... }
```

The above `location` blocks can appear in any order. Only regular expressions are sensitive to evaluation order.